# Datewise filter not working properly in sequelize using nodejs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want filter date wise data from mysql Db

my sequelize query like

```
...........
var filterKey = "DATE_ADDED"
var filterValue = "2016-12-27 00:00:00" 
    return myDb.myTable.findAndCountAll({
                                    attributes: ['ID', 'NAME', 'FIRSTNAME'],
                                    where: {

                                      [filterKey]: {
                                        like: '%' +  filterValue + '%'
                                      }
                                    },
                                    order: [
                                      [sortField, orderField],
                                      ['NAME'],
                                      ['ID']
                                    ],
                                    offset: currentPage,
                                    limit: numPerPage
                                  })
                                  .then((getCountandCustomer) => {
    .....................
    .....................

    })
```

In command promp showing this **error** [image]

Comment: I think the "important" peace of code is missing in your example. I don't see a date field. Or where are you passing it?

Comment: now i passing filterKey and filterValue please refer the code

Comment: I think sequelize does not like a timestamp value to be set like this. 
Do you want to get entries from the exact timestamp or just on this day?